# Is there any performance issue with Transactional replication in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp, transactional-replication

In my Organization, we do have a requirement to get last hour modified data from production database (some of the large tables) to other support teams.

So, we are suggesting to go with replication.  However, Our DBA is saying that replication is failure model (they are saying it will slow down the performance).

Our DBAs are suggesting a approach to introduce new column to those tables and track the last modified time.. They will export those records using bcp utility and provide that data to other support teams. .. Is this approach good?

Is there any specific issues exist with SQL Server replication?

Please suggest the general industry practice on this scenario..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you (dev/junior) are questioning your DBA recommendation :) As always it depends, you should talk with your DBA why he thinks so. Anyway you don't describe your environment, data volume, etc.

Comment: yes..;-)..Our data environment more like OLTP system..However, now the system allowed with some bulk process..Most of those publication tables records count will be in lakhs and data growth is less too..One or two table have more than 20 million records.. So I would like to know general industry practice on this scenario..